# mysql query to select registered users from 4pm to 6am of next day, and from 6am to 4pm again

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, cron

i have developed a php scrpit which automatically creates excel lists of users, 
 everyday at 4pm and  6am.
The problem is the select query, as every list contains the old registered users, + the new registered which are selected autmatically in cron job.
what i need is to select only users registered from 4pm to 6am of next day, and another select for users registered from 6am to 4pm of the same day.

any direction or tip would be great.
thank you.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass');  
mysqli_select_db($conn, 'dbname');  

$setSql = "SELECT * FROM sys";
$setRec = mysqli_query($conn,$setSql);

$columnHeader ='';
$columnHeader = "UID"."\t"."Name"."\t"."Number"."\t";


$setData='';

while($rec = mysqli_fetch_row($setRec))  
{
  $rowData = '';
  foreach($rec as $value)       
  {
    $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    $rowData .= $value;
  }
  $setData .= trim($rowData)."\n";
}

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Tirane');

echo 'Current Server Time:' . date('m/d/Y H:i:s a') ;

$name='export_'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.xls';
$xen=ucwords($columnHeader)."\n".$setData."\n";
echo $xen;
file_put_contents($name, $xen);

?>
```

the code above is execute in cron job everyday at 4pm and 6am.
how it should work:
6am execution-> select all users registered from 4pm of previous day until 6am(when the script is run)
4pm execution-> select all useres registered from 6am to 4pm of the same day.

the script creates a different excel file, with the filename as date+time of creation date and time, and saves the file in the server. 
all the files available are shown on another page, and are available to download to the user.

how it actually works:
script1 executed at 4pm -> select all users registered until 4pm.
script2 executed at 6am of next day -> selects all users from script1 + new registrations done from 4pm to 6am of next day.
script1 again executed at 4pm -> select users from 6AM to 4PM, without the same users selected from script2.

i want script2 to deselect or not select same users that script1 would return, meaning that there will be no same data in script1 and script2 output.

edit: perhaps i will need to add a date& time column in the table to achieve this?

edit2: clearer explanation:
'userX' registers at 3PM, so the script executed at 4PM, will return 'userX'.
'userY' registers at 7PM, so the script executed at 6AM, should return only 'userY' and not 'userX'.
'userZ' registers at 10AM, so the script executed at 4PM, will return only 'userZ'.

Comment: please provide all the needed code/scripts so you can get some help based on your work.

Comment: edited the post. thank you

Comment: ***@masterNixe***: if you can accommodate a `datetime` column in the table, your job would be easier.

Comment: yes i wrote it in the first edit in the question, so, assuming that the datetime column is added, whats next?

Comment: why is my question downvoted... not enough explanation?

Answer (score 1):

it will be better if you can provide some sample data and your desired output, but 
as per my understanding from your question ,below code will work for you

```
if(hour(current_timestamp)) =6
Then 
     select users 
     from table_name 
     where hour(datetime) between 6 and 15; 
elseif(hour(current_timestamp)) =16
Then  
     select users 
     from table_name 
     where hour(datetime) between 6 and 15; 
end if;
```

Comment: thank you for your input, i edited the question, perhaps its clearer now?